# What is the difference between GPRS, HSPA and HSDPA?

Tags: wireless-networking, gprs, hsdpa

In wireless communication we use the above services to access the internet. What are the differences between the above technologies. I know that there are differences in speeds but I expect some statistical information or technology definition like thing. I mean a good comparison :)

Update :

I am adding the thing I realized..

HSPA is a common term that used to group 2 technologies. HSDPA and HSUPA. They are operated in UMTS networks.

GPRS works in GSM networks

Comment: Don't forget EDGE and UMTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPRS or [Generalized Packet Radio Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Packet_Radio_Service) is generally associated with 2G networks and provides data rates of 56-114 kbit/s.

HSPA or [High Speed Packet Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Speed_Packet_Access) describes a family of related cellular data protocols.

HSDPA or [High-Speed Downlink Packet Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Speed_Downlink_Packet_Access) is a particular HSPA protocol and currently provides for speeds of 1.8, 3.6, 7.2 and 14.0 Mbit/s.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia page for [**HSPA** mobile telephony protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Speed_Packet_Access)
A Short [comparative-description page](http://www.clove.co.uk/viewTechInfo.aspx?Content=3B2BD491-6465-4C70-ABDB-5A12A06C3D8D&Category=TECHINFO) reference.
[**AT&T** reference page](http://developer.att.com/developer/index.jsp?page=toolsTechDetail&id=7600078).

Comment: Maybe you could summarize the contents of those websites.

Comment: Yes, please summarize.